# Phalcon 3.0 Model Relationships

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm building a tiny project using Phalcon 3.0.1 just to learn how to use ORM model relationships between two tables and just on the start encountered first problem with joining data from related tables. Here's my SQL code for those tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `how_to_apply` text NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_categories` (`categories_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='utf8_general_ci'


CREATE TABLE `categories` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `category_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='utf8_general_ci'
```

Jobs has a foreign key for categories (categories_id). Now, trying to init relationship in my categories model like:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasManay('id', 'Jobs', 'categories_id', ['alias' => 'Jobs']);
    }
```

Now when calling find method `Categories::find()` is not returning related data from Jobs table. I've also notice that I can put anything stupid inside `hasMany()` method and it even won't catch exception. It looks like it is completely ignored. I can even do something like below and it won't crash.

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasManay('stupid', 'Doesnt_exist_table', 'more_stupid', ['alias' => 'Jobs']);
    }
```

I would like to also outline that all properties in my models are public. I've gone trough all the docs, other stackoverflow questions, github examples and I believe that should work. Any help will be appreciated as I'm going mad about it.

Comment: There is a typo in hasMany (hasManay) method, but this come to play while posting a question and has nothing to the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Test case:

```
class Jobs extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('categories_id', 'Categories', 'id');
    }
}

class Categories extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Jobs', 'categories_id');
    }
}

class TestController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        // get the first job
        $job = Jobs::findFirst();
        // get the (single) category that is related to this job
        $jobCategory = $job->getRelated('Categories');


        // get the first category
        $category = Categories::findFirst();
        // get all the jobs related to this category
        $jobsInThisCategory = $category->getRelated('Jobs');
    }
}
```

The related records will only be called when you do `->getRelated()` on your object.
So if you defined your relation as

```
$this->hasMany('stupid', 'Doesnt_exist_table', 'more_stupid', ['alias' => 'Jobs']);
```

And you call `$category->getRelated('Jobs')`, you will get an error because that table `Doesnt_exist_table` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;


class Categories extends Model
{

    // ....

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Articles', 'categories_id', array(
            'alias' => 'Categories',
            'reusable' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Articles extends Model
{

    // ....

    public function initialize()
   {
       $this->belongsTo("categories_id",  __NAMESPACE__ . "\Categories", "id", array(
          'alias' => 'Categories',
          'reusable' => true
        ));
   }

   public function getCategories($parameters = null)
   {
       return $this->getRelated('Categories', $parameters);
   }

}
```

In Controller:

```
 public function indexAction()
{ 
    $articles = Articles::find([
      'order' => 'id DESC',
      'limit' => 2
    ]);
    $this->view->setVar('articles',$articles);
}
```

In View(Volt):

```
{% for article in articles %}
  {{ article.title }}
  // ...
  {# Show Categories #}
  {{ article.categories.name }}
 {#  or #}
 {{ article.categories.id }}
 {#  or #}
 {{ article.categories.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```